# This simple script doesn't work

Tags: python, error-handling

This simple Python script doesn't work.

```
   import time
   import random

    callingcard = ('BootsOnTheGround', 'TitanBaseCamp', 'TitanFacility',
   'TitanicStorm', 'TitanicCanyon', 'TitanSandstorm', 'ToTheShip',
   'AsteroidMines', 'TheSteelDragon', 'C6Assembly', 'C12Patrol')

    weapons = ('Rack-9', 'Karma-45', 'NV-4', 'R3K', 'KBAR-   32', 'Trencher', 'Type-2', 'Volk', 'ERAD', 'FHR40', 'RPR Evo', 'KBS Longbow', 'DMR-1', 'Widowmaker', 'Banshee', 'DCM-8', 'Reaver', 'RAW', 'Mauler', 'Titan', 'EMC', 'Oni', 'Kendall 44', 'Hailstorm', 'OSA', 'MacTav-45', 'TF-141', 'S-Ravage', 'M1', 'Hornet', 'Spartan SA3', 'P-LAW', 'Howitzer')

    while True:
        print("Open Supply Drop?.")
        answer = input().lower()
        if answer == "yes":
            print("Weapons or Calling Card?")
            answer1 = input().lower()
            if answer1 == "Calling Card":
                print("Please wait 3 seconds...")
                time.sleep(3)
               print(random.choice(callingcard))
            elif answer1 == "Weapons":
                print ("Please wait 3 seconds...")
                time.sleep(3)
                print(random.choice(weapons))
            else:
                print("Please wait 3 seconds...")
            time.sleep(3)
            break
       else:
           print("Please wait 3 seconds...")
       time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: It works until the 'Weapons or Calling Card?' bit, then waits 3 seconds, then shows '>>>'

Comment: You might want to take a look at your identation.

Comment: I messed up the indentions trying to make the code formatted into the question

Comment: which python are you using ?

Comment: print itlself says its 3.+ what is the error you getting @AlexLuu

Comment: `print()` also works in `python 2.x`

Comment: if he is using `python 2.x` then he must use `raw_input` instead of `input()` function.

Comment: you need to import __future__ before to use print() in python. here there is no __future__ package was imported

Answer (score 3):

You were taking input as `answer1 = input().lower` and changing it to lowercase, so it was not matching with any condition. Change it to `answer1 = input()`.

I have edited your code to work.

```
import time
import random

callingcard = ('BootsOnTheGround', 'TitanBaseCamp', 'TitanFacility',
   'TitanicStorm', 'TitanicCanyon', 'TitanSandstorm', 'ToTheShip',
   'AsteroidMines', 'TheSteelDragon', 'C6Assembly', 'C12Patrol')

weapons = ('Rack-9', 'Karma-45', 'NV-4', 'R3K', 'KBAR-   32', 'Trencher', 'Type-2', 'Volk', 'ERAD', 'FHR40', 'RPR Evo', 'KBS Longbow', 'DMR-1', 'Widowmaker', 'Banshee', 'DCM-8', 'Reaver', 'RAW', 'Mauler', 'Titan', 'EMC', 'Oni', 'Kendall 44', 'Hailstorm', 'OSA', 'MacTav-45', 'TF-141', 'S-Ravage', 'M1', 'Hornet', 'Spartan SA3', 'P-LAW', 'Howitzer')

while True:
    print("Open Supply Drop?.")
    answer = input().lower()
    if answer == "yes":
        print("Weapons or Calling Card?")
        answer1 = input()
        if answer1 == "Calling Card":
            print("Please wait 3 seconds...")
            time.sleep(3)
            print(random.choice(callingcard))
        elif answer1 == "Weapons":
            print ("Please wait 3 seconds...")
            time.sleep(3)
            print(random.choice(weapons))
        else:
            print("Please wait 3 seconds...")
        time.sleep(3)
        break
    else:
        print("Please wait 3 seconds...")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: It would be more robust to still use `input.lower()`, but compare to lower-case terms. E.g. change "Calling Card" to "calling card", as that would accept input like "CaLliNG CarD" as well.

Comment: Your answer is right, but maybe it's better to keep the `input.lower()` and put the string in the conditions entirely in lowercase. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking answer1 == "Weapon1" but before that you made it into lowercase.

so, either remove `answer1.lower()` or check `answer1 == "weapon1"`
then it will work...

```
mohideen@botvfx-dev:~$ python3 ~/Desktop/s.py 
Open Supply Drop?.
yes
Weapons or Calling Card?
weapons
Please wait 3 seconds...
Spartan SA3
mohideen@botvfx-dev:~$
```